# How to calculate the date to send notification daily/weekly/monthly repetitively after certain date

Tags: php, drupal-8

I have a specific date like 2021-01-07 from when some event should start. After starting, system should send notification daily or weekly or even monthly based on the values chosen by the user. So how can i calculate the  daily/weekly/monthly date to send notice every month?

I tried using time offset like this:

- event starting date + 7 days (for weekly)
- event starting date + 3 weeks (for month) so on
  but this only works for the month for starting date not for future months.

This notification functionalities  is triggered  when some event occurs on the site. can not use cronjob task statically.

Comment: You could keep a `nextNotificationDate` in your database and then have a cron job run daily to send the notifications scheduled for the current date.

Comment: You can calculate the date with a `Datetime` object, [adding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) a Dateinterval like `P1W` (one week) or `P1M` (one month)